# What is a "local" subnetwork

Tags: subnet

I understand that subnetwork, or subnet, represents all machines that belong to the same local area network (LAN). But I don't understand what it means by a local subnetwork. Can someone explain this term?

Context: "The software can search machines that are using the same software in the same local subnet."

Comment: Can you post a link to where you saw the term used, or quote the text?  Seeing the context will help people understand what the author was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

A large organization may have a very large LAN consisting of many different subnetworks.  Your "local subnet" would be the subnet your machine in connected to.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, they are referring to the block of IP addresses that your LAN "exists" on.

For instance, your router might be at `192.168.1.1` and has a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`. This means that your LAN's subnet (expressed in [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)) is `192.168.1.0/24`.

This subnet includes all IP addresses from `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255`.

Since `192.168.1.0` and `192.168.1.255` are reserved addresses and `192.168.1.1` is being used by the router, this means that you can effectively use any IP address from `192.168.1.2` through `192.168.1.254` on your LAN. The router cannot "see" any traffic that doesn't originate from one of these addresses (with the exception of traffic coming from the internet).

Wikipedia has a pretty detailed [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your definitions (and I don't agree with your definition of LAN), a "Local Subnetwork" would be what most networking professionals would call a subnet.

A subnet is a number of machines with IP address in the same range and which can talk to each other without going through a router.

In the case of a typical system, one might have a network of 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.254.  Any machine in this range can talk to any other machine in that range directly, ie no router.

A LAN stands for a local area network of-course.  The thing is that a LAN can still be broken up into multiple subnets - the thing being that they are all connected together without going through a longer distance connection.    An easy way of imagining this might be an office with different subnets for Sales, Helpdesk and Management - but all sharing the same network connection, ie different subnets, same LAN.